# The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

Now, I am trying to set selenium on Ruby and I want to change it from headless mode to normal mode but I don't know how to do it.

I thought that I just should remove add_argument but it didn't work.

```
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    # options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    @driver = driver || Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
    @driver.get("https://test.com")
```

The error says

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.)
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.
```

Is there any setting that I am missing ?
Please kindly give me any advice.

Thank you

Comment: It's bit difficult to handle the options from selenium. There is a good wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding called WATIR. We can easily set everything. If you are ready take WATIR, let me know I will teach you how to set all these options.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry but just to make sure, you meant that it is hard to run Selenium not using headless mode? I thought I have seen something like that before, I don't know how to do it though. 

Also, thank you for telling me about WATIR, I am reading a document now, but can it handle the option like proxy with authentication? because I am trying to make my script normal mode in order to set the extension for the proxy with authentication and the extension is not supported in chrome headless mode.

Comment: You can do all things in WATIR in a more easy way because it sits at the top of selenium. If you want me to write an answer in WATIR, then tag WATIR and let me know

Comment: @Rajagopalan
I have yet to set WAITIR but I am wondering if setting selenium to be able to check on browser is that difficult? I just want to set it not to use headless mode...

Comment: maybe there's local variable `driver` existed (with --headless), so your logic `@driver = driver || S...` will not create a new `Selenium::WebDriver` (without --headless) as you want.